# How to get the event target in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery ui to do the drag and drop. I want to do something on the draggable item after I drop it.

I have something like this..

```
     $('#drag-me').draggable({
         scroll:false,
         cursor:'pointer',
         revert: 'invalid'
     });

    $('.box').droppable({
        drop:function(event, ui){
            //I want to append the #drag-me element to the .box. How do I do that?
            //event.target -> get .box not #drag-me
            $(this).appendTo(event.target)
        }
    })
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is why reading the docs is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `ui.draggable`, as per the `droppable` API `drop` event docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

So you would do:

```
$('.box').droppable({
    drop:function(event, ui){
        $(this).appendTo(ui.draggable)
    }
});
```